# How can I do this kind of 3D camera movement in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

This is a school project. I have a big cube which is like a planet. I have a small cube that can move on every side of the cube planet. The player moves forward automatically on its local z axis and I rotate it by 90 or -90 degrees to move left or right- but the player can control it like it's an up-down-left-right movement (made a script so they don't have to rotate the cube with 2 keys). It's like a Tron game so if I press the up key, I can't press down immediately because I leave a trail so I have to press the left or right keys. I have a problem with my camera movement. The camera follows the little cube from above, but I want it to lean a little when the little cube player gets close to the edge of a side so it lets me see the other side - where I'm planning to go.

I have a script where I use the center of the cube planet and the player's center as the direction vector and multiply it with the camera-player distance.

```
Vector3 direction = (target.position - center.position).normalized;         
transform.position = target.position + direction * distance;
```

Then I point my camera's forward vector to the player cube's direction. I tried two codes but none of them worked perfectly. First I tried to rotate the camera with:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(-direction);
```

[Shown in video](https://youtu.be/i1D83StILfw). The problem with this is that since I don't tell the program the Up and Right vectors (I think), it sets them for itself to some random numbers so the camera sometimes do its own thing like it does a pirouette.

Next I tried this:

```
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.forward, -direction);                                                                          
transform.Rotate(rot.eulerAngles, Space.World);
```

[Shown in video](https://youtu.be/XPLOZaJWOCE). It's almost good but as the little cube moves, the camera starts steering slightly in the beginning and it gets worse and worse.

Do you have any ideas how can I make it work? I hope you understand what I would like to achieve. I'm trying to set the camera as to always show that when I press Up, my cube moves upward, when I press Right my cube always goes right etc. and when I reach the edge of my side the camera leans a bit towards the side I'm moving to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dot product to find which orthogonal direction of your cube is closest to the camera's current up.

```
Vector3 closestToUp;
float greatestDot = 0f;
foreach (Vector3 dir in new Vector3[]{
        target.forward, target.right, -target.forward, -target.right})
{
    float curDot = Vector3.Dot(dir,transform.up);
    if (curDot > greatestDot) 
    {
        greatestDot = curDot;
        closestToUp = dir;
    }
}
```

Than, use that direction as the second parameter of `Quaternion.LookRotation`. This will keep its local up direction as aligned with the cube's "top" as possible given whatever new forward direction:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(-direction, closestToUp);
```

Comment: Your edit works perfectly, it's just what I wanted to do, thank you very much for the help!